# eclipse BigInteger compilation issue

Tags: java, eclipse, biginteger

I am using Java 1.6.0_45. I have a simple java code that uses BigInteger. It runs fine when I run from command line (javac and then java )

Now, when I run the same code from eclipse, I get a compilation error! I printed the version of java in both the runs and the java run time version is the same.

Here is the code:

```
import java.math.*;

public class BigInteger2 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
          BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("3");
     }
}
```

The error (only in Eclipse) that I get is the following :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The constructor BigInteger(String) is undefined at BigInteger2.main(BigInteger2.java:10)
```

It is basically complaining about new BigInteger("3")

What am I missing here? Some configuration setting in eclipse? Why does it run fine when I compile and invoke from command line and why doesnt it run in eclipse? please suggest. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have your own class `BigInteger` in the same directory, which is hiding Java's standard `BigInteger` class? Delete your own `BigInteger` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `project -> right click -> Properties -> java Build Path -> Libraries`
and check your version of `JRE System Library`

`BigInteger` is present since JDK 1.1, but am not sure about the `String constructor`

Answer (score 1):

try clean and build the project and then run the prog

Comment: can you try clean and build using ant (or) maven

Comment: ant or maven.... hmm...why make it so complicated ? I mean i am importing java.math.*; and it is a simple 2 lines program...

Comment: A sample Ant file will be like below,  update "build/classes" to the your output path, then Run it

<project>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target> 
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>
</project>

Comment: The error is likely somewhere else. OP imports `java.math.*`, and BigInteger's String constructor is available in the JDK for sure... If the JDK used to run the program is really the one in the post...

Comment: My guess too, that some old BigInteger.java resulted in a BigInteger.class that is still lying around. Hence the proposed "clean". (The IDE automatically compiles in the background.)

Answer (score 1):

What is the JDK/JRE you have set up in the Preferences under Java->Installed JRE's? Is it the same JDK you referring to in your question?
Have you probably set the -vm parameter in your eclipse.ini to an older JDK? You may provide the -vm Parameter there to ensure that the right JDK is used to start eclipse itself. 
[ http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html ]